# FOP hyphenation can't build spanish patterns

Tags: apache-fop, hyphenation

I am using FOP (version 2.3.0). When I try to compile the Spanish patterns I downloaded from OFFO running `ant jar-hyphenation`, I get next error:

```
compile-hyphenation:
 [java] Processing /home/pf/MEGA/prg/java/fop/trunk/fop/hyph/es.xml
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 [java]     at org.apache.fop.hyphenation.TernaryTree.insert(TernaryTree.java:180)
 [java]     at org.apache.fop.hyphenation.TernaryTree.insert(TernaryTree.java:244)
```

And the last line of output is repeated a zillion of times.

Other patterns are compiled without problems, but when I include the Spanish ones, the build process crashes. Just to be sure the file was not corrupted, I downloaded a more recent version of es.xml but ant is still crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2569, I found the solution:

> The recursion at
>   org.apache.fop.hyphenation.TernaryTree.insert(TernaryTree.java:244) is
>   correct, but it requires more stack size. Fix:
>
> ```
> >diff build.xml~ build.xml
> 184c184
> < <property name="hyph.stacksize" value="512k"/>
> —
> > <property name="hyph.stacksize" value="1M"/>
> ```

The build process just needed a bigger stack. The build.xml file to be modified resides in the parent directory of the hyph directory. I increased the stack and was just able to compile everything.